# writing a class that iterates over a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby, class, hash

I'm having trouble writing a class to iterate over a hash of hashes or nested hash, here is an example of the hash I have.

```
 hash = {a => {:number => 1, :color => "blue", :language => english} b => {:number => 2, :color => "red", :language => english}
```

I want to write class methods that will return the number of each parent

Comment: `a`, `english` and `b` are not literals.  You need a comma between the two hashes and a `}` at the end. Perhaps you want `:a`, `:b` and `"english"`.  Please edit to correct. Always test your examples with IRB or PRY before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a method, not a class.  Here are a couple of approaches you could use.

```
def numbers(h)    
  Hash[h.map { |k,v| [k, v[:number]] }]
end

h = { :a => {:number => 1, :color => "blue", :language => "english" },
      :b => {:number => 2, :color => "red",  :language => "english" } }

numbers(h)
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

or with Ruby 2.1:

```
def numbers(h)    
  h.map { |k,v| [k, v[:number]] }.to_h
end
```

Another way that returns the same hash:

```
def numbers(h)    
  h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = v[:number] }
end
```